# Read package.json in Ember application

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs, yeoman

We have the following structure (shown just some relevant components) for our `yeoman` (`grunt`) based `Ember.js` project:

```
myapp/
├── app
├── component.json
├── package.json
├── Gruntfile.js
├── README.md
│   ├── adapters
│   ├── application.js
│   ├── components
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── generated
│   ├── images
│   ├── models
│   ├── routes
│   ├── scripts
│   ├── styles
│   ├── templates
│   └── views
├── dist
├── node_modules
└── test
```

We need to access, in `application.js`, some of the values in `package.json` and `component.json`. We would like to access this during the deploy process (as a `grunt` task?). Is this possible? How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a ready to use grunt package like this https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace for this kind of task, most common use case is for example to extract the version number and stamp your javascript files with it during a grunt run

example implementation ***(haven't tested it)***:

in your **Gruntfile.js**:

```
...
replace: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            variables: {
                version: '<%= pkg.version %>'
            }
        },
        prefix: '@@',
        files: [
            {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['app/application.js', 'app/README.md'], dest: 'dist/'}
        ]
    }
}
...
```

**application.js**

```
...
var App = Framework.Application.create({
    VERSION: @@version,
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')` to read json from a file for a grunt task.

Comment: That looks interesting. How can I pass the `json hash` just parsed to my `application.js` in the grunt task?